# Configure the maximum number of co-authoring authors in SharePoint 2013 at Farm Level

Tags: central-administration, farm-admin, co-authoring, pnp-powershell

With the help of below script and based on my requirement I am able to set my limit for co-authoring the authors for sharepoint documents at site collection level

```
$siteurl = "SiteURL"
$mysite=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
$mysite.WebApplication.WebService.CoauthoringMaxAuthors = <MaxAuthors>
$mysite.WebApplication.WebService.Update()
```

But I would like to implement the script or **Tune** the option if exists at SharePoint farm level.Can any one help me how can I achieve this